# State not updating with dynamic checkboxes

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

**UPDATE:** I ended up just switching from a section list to a scrollview, and the state updated correctly. I didn't understand the Pure Component thing, and that is the reason that it wasn't rerendering.

I'm pretty new to react native and I'm figuring out a lot of things with redux and such. However, I can't seem to understand why my component is not updating when the state changes. I am not sure how much information is necessary, so I'll try to put comments in the code that should be focused on.

Checkboxes are rendered dynamically from an api call. I then use that data to create a list of items that have a true/false value to pass to the checkboxes. The keys in the list is associated specifically with each checkbox. I am trying to keep this as dynamic as possible to allow changes in data on the backend. When the checkbox is pressed, the CHECK dispatch fires and updates the state as expected, but the checkbox is not updated to reflect that state. Printing the state of the checkedList shows that the state IS being updated correctly. The redux and everything is working, but the checkedness of the checkbox is not changing.

The big question is: Why does the checkbox not update with the new state?

Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows:

Details.js (Container)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { actionCreators } from '../redux/actionCreators'
import DetailsScreen from '../components/DetailsScreen';  

class Details extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { getRouteList } = this.props
    getRouteList()
  }

  render() {
    const { listReady, routeList, checkedList, check } = this.props
    return (
      <DetailsScreen
        sections={routeList}
        listReady={listReady}
        checkedList={checkedList} //passing list of items with true/false values to DetailsScreen
        check={check} //function that calls an actionCreators(dispatch) below **this works**
      />
    )
  }    
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  listReady: state.listReady,
  routeList: state.routeList,
  checkedList: state.checkedList //list of items that correlate with the checked state of the checkboxes, e.g. state.checkedList[0] = Item1: true
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getRouteList: () => {
    dispatch(actionCreators.getRouteList())
  },
  check: key => {
    dispatch(actionCreators.check(key))
  }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Details)
```

DetailsScreen.js (Component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, SectionList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Button, CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { actionCreators } from '../redux/actionCreators'

const extractKey = ({ id }) => id

class DetailsScreen extends Component {
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const {checkedList, check} = this.props
    return (
      <CheckBox
        title={item.Description}
        checked={checkedList[item.Description]} //getting the state of the checkbox from checkedList **this works, initially shows up correctly, but does not get updated**
        checkedIcon='plus-square'
        checkedColor='blue'
        uncheckedIcon='minus-circle'
        uncheckedColor='red'
        onPress={() => check(item.Description)} //action creator helper that switches the state of the item (true/false)
      />
    )
  }

  renderSectionHeader = ({ section }) => {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.header}>
        {section.title}
      </Text>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { sections, listReady } = this.props
    if (listReady) {
      return (
        <SectionList
          style={styles.container}
          sections={sections}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
          keyExtractor={extractKey}
        />
      )
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = *styles for stuff above*

export default DetailsScreen
```

actionCreators.js

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native"

export const actionCreators = {
  check: key => {
    return {
      type: types.CHECK,
      payload: key //item.Description from the checkbox
    }
  },
  getRouteList: () => {
    return {
      type: types.GET_ROUTE_LIST,
      payload:
        fetch(url)
          .then(result => result.json()) //result is formed for a React Native SectionList
          .catch(() => [])
    }
  }
*other actions*
}
```

reducer.js

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'

export const initialState = {
  routeList: [],
  checkedList: {},
  listReady: false,
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action

  switch (type) {
    case types.CHECK:
      console.log(state.checkedList) //shows that the state IS indeed being updated, but it is not changing on the checkbox
      return {
        ...state,
        checkedList: {...state.checkedList, [payload]: !state.checkedList[payload]} 
      }

    case types.GET_ROUTE_LIST_FULFILLED:
      list = {}
      payload[0].data.map((item) => { //
        if (item.Description == "Route 1") { //test to make sure that that the checkboxes were initially getting set correctly
          list[item.Description] = true
        }
        else list[item.Description] = false
      })
      return {
        ...state,
        routeList: payload, //checkboxes are rendered with this 
        listReady: true,
        checkedList: list //this holds the state of the checkedness of the checkboxes **updated in CHECK reducer**
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not react-native expert but problems are 'normal react' related.

Minor ones: there sould be a `key` property in `<CheckBox >` - use `index` parameter in `renderItem`

More problematic is a data-structure / parameter passing. `SectionList` is a `pureComponent` - for performance reason uses shallow equal - doesn't rerender when data not change. But even if it was normal component it wouldn't work ;) - `SectionList` gets props that not change - `sections` (`sections={routeList}`).

`routeList` is not updated then `SectionList` isn't rerendered. `SectionList` doesn't know that item (`<CheckBox >`) uses `checkedList`.

### HOW TO FIX?

1. You can combine (in render) `checkedList` with `sections` (mark checked sections/items) to create new `sectionsChecked` array passed as 'sections'. Every call to render will create new array forcing `SectionList` refresh.
2. As above but using `mapStateToPorps`.
3. Leave all as is but make `SectionList` feeling that it gets new data - it's enougth to pass new reference. Pass a copy of `sections` using any method you like which results in new object/array.

3-rd method may not be good enough method as renderItem should be provided with data as props (f.e. 'checked' defined in each section) - pureComponent refreshing problem - it shouldn't be a deep object property/derived data.

It's all described in docs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 3rd option here? Would you recommend using something other than section list that would allow the checkbox to be updated independent of the list? Scrollview or something like it?

Comment: 3rd option could not be optimal option ... SectionList is probably optimized and will work well with good data (options 1,2)... however you can try to 'add a layer' renderItem using <Item /> (embed Checkbox inside <Item />) with `shouldComponentUpdate` to optimize rendering (render <Checkbox...)

Comment: Do you think you could give an example for that? I'm not sure what you mean? I'll accept the answer.

Comment: sth like: `<SectionList sections={sections.slice()}` - but this is ugly trick, you should fix data structures (1,2) instead of looking for workarounds